Does the Firebase Admin SDK support workload identity federation ？
Recently, we made the service account key and saw a box that said

Service account keys could pose a security risk if compromised. We recommend that you avoid downloading service account keys and instead use the Workload Identity Federation. You can learn more about the best way to authenticate service accounts on Google Cloud here.

I am using the firebase admin sdk version 6.8.1 to send clouding message, now we are using workload identity federation instead of the service account key json file:
String workloadCredential = workloadCredentialsMap.get(pline);

InputStream serviceAccount = new ClassPathResource(workloadCredential).getInputStream();
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setProjectId(projectIdsMap.get(pline))
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl).build();
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, pline);

But we got the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Authentication backend unknown error.",
    "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
}

So does the Firebase Admin SDK  support workload identity federation? Is there any other way to handle the situation?
I tried and got the above

Not according to this GitHub Action https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#inputs-workload-identity-federation
